# Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:34811/

Tags: docker, selenium, cucumber, bitbucket, pipeline

I'm hoping someone will offer some help here.

I tried following the similar questions asked before but no change in the results.

I'm trying to run a VS 2019 .Net 5.0 project in a bitbucket pipeline but I'm getting the following error when I try initialise a new chromeDriver (`OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:34811/`)

Here is the copy of the yml I'm using (I've tried both the commented and uncommented version but both getting the same result)
[bitbucket-yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKpVT.png)

Further information about this project is, it's a Selenium/Nunit project in c# running Cucumber feature files.

Locally I'm able to run the project in parallel but only getting issues when trying to run in the pipeline.

Any advice would greatly be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

is your HUB url is working ?

**http://[your host]:4444**

Sometimes this error will be thrown when any OS patch upgrade happened on your driver machine. so please restart your docker image.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-v3.yml restart
```

Any OS upgrade happened or patch happened, I suggest to restart.

Still not working, please use this official yml file

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/docker-compose-v3.yml

Comment: Sorry dont think the first option did anything or I might've not done it right.

Comment: is you hub url working ?

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand that.  I’m trying to run the suite through a bit bucket pipeline, not locally from my machine?

Comment: Is your port right.? We should always use 4444 port. Is that error occurring all the time.?

Comment: @JayanthBala Could you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73017893/openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-cannot-start-the-driver-service-on-http-l