# 'Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:39147/ ' while running Docker Image

Tags: c#, docker, selenium, .net-core, selenium-chromedriver

I have problem with `Selenium` when I want to create a Image in Docker. In fact, I developed a `.Net Core Api` using `Selenium Chrome driver` and I need to create its `Docker container` to deploy it on a server. The interesting point is that it works properly locally, but I face an error when I create its Image and try to run it. 
It could but helpful to share my code.

It is a piece of code in which I instansiate `chrome driver` :

```cs
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
   options.AddArgument("headless");

   driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome:latest AS base
WORKDIR /app

# build and copy dotnet project
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
COPY bin/Release/net5.0/publish/ app/
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Pand.dll"]
```

And this is an error after I use `docker run -p 8080:80 pand/backend` command:

> Cannot assign requested address [::1]:39147 (localhost:39147) crit:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[6]
> Application startup exception
> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:39147/
> at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.Start()
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command
> commandToExecute)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver..ctor(ChromiumDriverService
> service, ChromiumOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service,
> ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)

Comment: Avoid executing as a root user and remove the argument `no-sandbox`

Comment: I remove it and recreate my image but still I have that error

Comment: @undetectedSelenium But I didn't get 'Avoiding executing as a root user'. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Could you see if running this in the container returns anything useful?
`sudo lsof -i:39147 `

Comment: No it returns nothing

Comment: Which version of Chrome and ChromeDriver are you using? They are separate components (e.g. Chrome.exe and ChromeDriver.exe), but their major versions should match (e.g. Chrome 104.x needs ChromeDriver 104.x).